# Android NDK: Create a library with undefined function

Tags: c++, makefile, android-ndk, linker

I'm new to makefiles. I'm trying to make an Android makefile for Box2D. I did some modifications to the library in that way that it uses some minor math functions from my own game. So basically I have written in a file of Box2D:

```
extern float fastCos(float);
extern float fastSin(float);
```

But the makefile I have tries to link it as well, which is not what I want, because those two functions are implemented in the source of my game and obviously I'm only building Box2D at that time. I want the linker to link these functions only at the time I compile my whole game.

What should I do in the makefile to achieve this type of linking behavior? I've seen something in other makefiles on the web like "static_library" and "library", is that part of my problem?

Comment: Are you building Box2D separately or as part of your Android.mk process?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying. In order to avoid having to recompile box2d again, if I change something to make makefile of my own game. Just the way SDL does this job. If I change my own makefile, SDL doesn't get recompiled. It only gets re-linked.

Comment: Does the information from the link help? You need to build some kind of library, dynamic or static. 
http://navaneeth.github.io/blog/2013/07/28/building-static-and-shared-libraries-using-cmake/

Comment: No, not really, Android makefiles look totally different then CMake files.

Comment: Ah, now I get yer. 

Not easily using built in Android.mk facilities. I used ndk-build directly when I needed to make a library. https://tariqzubairy.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/arm-binaries-static-library-for-android/ Your Android.mk for the actual game can just use the static library.

Comment: The article you linked does not use a function that is not defined in the library itself. All functions are there. I'm trying to leave some functions open, so other libraries that are linked with this library can fill in these unimplemented functions.

Comment: It shouldn't matter?

Comment: Well, yeah I thought that as well, but I get this: `Box2D/Common/b2Math.h:127: error: undefined reference to 'fastSin(float)'`

Comment: Excuse me but I fail to understand what is the _need_ for declaring but not defining function in a library...? You're basically making the library a client of the client code, which is quite strange. Why not just plain externalizing your math in your own lib and use it in Box2D?

Answer (score 0):

After few more hours of searching and asking help from a friend, I managed to make it work.

The problem why it kept complaining about the undefined references is because the Android makefile mechanism automatically adds this linker flag:

```
-Wl,--no-undefined
```

After removing that flag in the makefiles of the NDK itself, it compiled just fine, as expected. However, there is of course another problem. Library A depends on lib B and vise versa, so there is no correct order of dynamic linking at runtime. So, as @JBL also pointed out, what I did was created another shared library (M) for these math functions. So now library A depends on library B and M and library B depends only on B. So, now we can load in this order: M, B, A.

After doing that, one could simply link the library B with this new M library without having to delete the linker flag `--no-undefined`. Because, now, everything is in place and we don't have circular dependencies anymore.